# How to add a service instance to a new server?

Tags: 2010, service-applications

Ok, lets say I have a custom service application.

I add a new server to my farm, and I want it to take on an "App Server" role.

I go to Central Admin -> Services on Server.  I select my newly added server.

I can stop the SharePoint Foundation Web Application service, and effectively stop my new server from being a WFE.

But, I don't see my custom service application in the list of services on my new server, so how do I add a service instance of my service to my new server, so I can start it?

I saw this [basically identical question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/16538/adding-a-new-server-to-the-farm-and-run-an-existing-service-application-on-it), but it does not provide a clear answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the answer is via Powershell, but not with any of the regular SharePoint Powershell cmdlets.

The way I got it to work was to create a custom Powershell cmdlet that took the server name as an input parameter, which then called my service instance class' constructor and added an instance to the specified server.

Comment: Please mark your answer as an answer.

Comment: It won't let me until tomorrow, but I will.

Answer (score 0):

What is your Service Application scoped to? If it is scoped to Web Applications, then it will never 'execute' on this server (because you've stopped the Web Application service, which you should never do anyways). If it is scoped to the Timer Service (as an example), then it will execute on any server in the farm, and so forth. SAs don't have a particular server they target (unless you've hardcoded it as such), instead they have a particular scope.

Only Service Instances show up on Services on Server.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand about the scope of a service.  The feature used to install the service is scoped to farm, and it installs the service and the service proxy on SPFarm.Local, and then installs a service instance on SPServer.Local, which I presume is whatever server it was that actually deployed the feature.  My question is, how do I get another service instance on another server? (I'm thinking Powershell.)  Also, and maybe this should be a whole new question, why should you never stop the Web Application service?